# Outdated responsive design tool in Safari

Tags: safari, development

It has been long time since I have seen an update on reponsive design tool in Safari - it looks straight from 2016-2017

Am I missing something that can be modified in order to show newer models? Because iOS version that can be seen on screenshot is relevant (16.0), however the models are dead old

I'm currently running macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (on 2018 13'3 MacBook Pro, if that matters)

[image]